# How to align a checkbox with specified column in table HTML

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 10px">
                    <div class="card m-b-30">
                        <div class="card-header container-fluid" ">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-12 table-responsive">
                                            <div id="order-listing_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper container-fluid dt-bootstrap4 no-footer">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                                        <table id="order-listing" class="table dataTable no-footer table-striped" style="border-bottom:1pt solid black" role="grid" aria-describedby="order-listing_info">
                                                            <thead>
                                                                <tr role="row">
                                                                    <th width="70%"><b>Name</b></th>
                                                                    <th><b>Active</b></th>
                                                                    <th><b>Select</b></th>
                                                                    <th><b>Delete</b></th>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </thead>
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                @*@foreach (var item in Model)
                                                                    {*@
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <div class="input-group">
                                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here" style="width: 450px; height: 40px">
                                                                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                                                                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
                                                                                    <i class="dripicons-search"></i>
                                                                                </button>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>

                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2">
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>

                                                                    <td>Test New</td>
                                                                    <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck"></td>
                                                                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-icons btn-inverse-secondary" id="data-editbtn-id"><div><i class="icon-pencil"></i></div></button></td>
                                                                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-icons btn-inverse-secondary" id="data-delete-id"><div><i class="dripicons-trash"></i></div></button></td>


                                                                </tr>


                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I tried aligning this checkbox with the Active column but my code doesn't align it with the specified column
whats wrong with my code?
some online HTML generates output the correct code with same code but when i edit it, the aligned doesn't work properly

I have attached my code above can anyone help me im using html and css for this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please give the below CSS, the input element is taking CSS of margin-left.

```
.form-check-input{
 margin:0 !important;
}
```

And also give this CSS

```
.table td, .table th{
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

Comment: I didn't still made the css i just only need to align the checkbox with the active column like shown above.